# Detecting a break _region_ in regression relationships (using R)

Tags: r, time-series, structural-change

We're given a seasonal time series $y_t$, representing a certain metric used to measure a system's performance. The measure has a positive trend, and a considerable seasonal influence.

We also know that, between $t_1$ and $t_2$, a number of changes were done to the system with the goal of improving performance. Our task is to measure if there was a significant impact of said changes. As doing an $A-B$ test is not feasible, we're left with detecting if there is a significant structural change following the aforementioned interval.

One approach would be detecting if a structural break-point occurs in $(t_1,t_2)$ using $R$'s *strucchange::breakpoints* function. My concern with this is that it is intended to detect **points** where structural changes occurs, whereas in our case the change (if it exists) most likely occurs in a smooth fashion in $(t_1,t_2)$.

Are there are any built in functionalities that could help me in this case? Or any theoretical approach that can be programmed? Or should my initial idea of using *strucchange::breakpoints* be sufficient?

**Note**: we're actually dealing with hundreds of such systems, so a computational solution is preferred, one that we can iterate through all the systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking out-loud for this answer, so there might be more statistically sound answers available.

One option would be to use ocular comparison because you already have your break points $\left(t_1,t_2\right)$.  You can use the calculations from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588971/control-charts-in-r/40497903#40497903) to create a control chart with new calculations starting at the break points.

Another potion is you can perform a regression analysis and transform your data by dividing each point by the slope.  The transformed data can then be run through `qicharts` in `R` with the `break` option exercised at $\left(t_1,t_2\right)$.

To be able to test for statistical significance, you could compare the means after each break to the "control" group (before any improvements were made) with a one sample t-test.  Plotting box plots of each transformed time region would help graphically display the results of your t-test.

Comment: I'll try this now and see how it goes. Just one question, what do you mean by ocular comparison? Is this some method I haven't heard of, or are you referring to interpreting the data visually? If the latter is the case, I'm afraid that's not an option - I'm dealing with a set of hundreds of such systems that need to be analyzed, so a purely computational solution is preferred.

Comment: @Sergiu, Yes, ocular comparison would simply be interpreting the data visually.  Had I known that you were dealing with hundreds of such systems (you may want to edit your question to include that information), I would have suggested simply skipping ahead to a `t-test` of the transformed data.